# Should p-values for chi-square and likelihood ratio chi-square tests be identical when estimated by Monte Carlo simulation?

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, likelihood-ratio

The question and answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169142/g-test-vs-pearsons-chi-squared-test?rq=1) suggest that the answer is “yes,” but my own analysis in SPSS suggests otherwise:

[image]

Note: I understand that the likelihood ratio chi-square and chi-square test are expected to yield different non-simulated (non-Monte Carlo) p-values simply because they have different statistical bases.

Edit: Also, if [degrees of freedom are inapplicable when applying a Monte Carlo simulation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/291540/why-are-the-degrees-freedom-not-available-when-i-conduct-a-monte-carlo-simulatio?rq=1), why is SPSS returning them here?